# Put a div with background over IMG

Tags: html, css

[what i'm trying to make it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKvNw.jpg)

I'm trying to put a div with a background over an img, I've looked over a lot of resources and when I make a background color the background color covers the whole image.

```
<div class="containerBox">
<div class="text-box">
  <h4> Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Oragnic Tea</h4>
</div>
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg">
```

```
.containerBox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.text-box {
   position: absolute;    
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;    
   width: 100%;
}
.text-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px; /*or whatever you want*/
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Are you aiming for a responsive layout? i.e. one that doesn't totally depend on the natural dimensions of the image? Or is the layout to be totally dictated by the size of the image (there are some very fixed dimensions in the picture you provide which seem to indicate a non-responsive layout is required).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that. Depends on what you specifically need.

If you can let go img tag and use background image (which is in general considered better), i recommend on using the following code snippet. (This may have extra lines of code but it solves the purpose, please delete these extra lines.)

```
<div class="containerBox">
    <div class="text-box">
        <h4> Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Oragnic Tea</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .text-box {
        display: grid;
        /* Or Flex */
        place-items: center;
        /* Or For Flex use align-items and justify-content */
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .text-box::before {
        content: '';
        background: url('https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 1;
        /* Opacity: as you like */
    }
    
    h4 {
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        height: 20%;
        width: 1000px;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
        /* Or whatever you want */
    }
</style>
```

If you want img tag:

```
.containerBox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

h4 {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 30%;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.555);
    /*or whatever you want*/
}

img {
    display: block;
}
```

If by background color you meant background color of text-box, then you need to reduce its heigth and width else use ::before pseudo selector and set its height and  width.

Comment: Thanks, Follow up question: is there a way to have this centered, I know that there is

Comment: for centering h4: 1. Use (display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;). 2. Use (display: grid; place-items: center;). 3. Use (display: block; [for h4 its by-default, so no need to write it] width: <100%; margin: auto;). 4. Use (parent { height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red; } child {background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px; position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }). For centering anything you must follow the above steps. If my answer was correct please click on the tick icon on my answer ao that i can claim it.